# Telethon utils.resolve_invite_link(link) is returning wrong Chat/Channel ID

Tags: python-3.x, telethon

I'm trying to generate the channel ID of my private channel in Telegram.

I use the following:

link = input("Please provide channel invite link: ")
print(utils.resolve_invite_link(link))

My output looks like the following (I've scrambled the numbers):

(0, 0123456789, 1234567891234567891)

When I view the private channel in the web browser, I get the channel ID as https://web.telegram.org/z/#-9876543210

So the channel ID should be -1009876543210, which I confirmed with IDBot.

Why isn't 9876543210 appearing when I call variable link within utils.resolve_invite_link()? That's the value I expected to see, not 0123456789.

Comment: From the documentation: __Note that the chat ID may not be accurate for chats with a link that were upgraded to megagroup, since the link can remain the same, but the chat ID will be correct once a new link is generated.__ https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/utils.html?highlight=resolve_invite_link#telethon.utils.resolve_invite_link

Comment: I read that too. But this is a brand new channel with 2 members and a bot.

Answer (score 2):

`utils.resolve_invite_link(link)`  no longer works with the new links.

Old links used to pack the channel/group ID inside the links themselves but this is no longer the case. The function will possibly be removed as well in future updates of the library https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/issues/1723

The most reliable way now is to use `CheckChatInviteRequest`  https://tl.telethon.dev/methods/messages/check_chat_invite.html

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question. Documentation from Telethon says utils.resolve_invite_link() supports the new channel links. So what gives??